# Prevent Closing Modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to prevent users from closing the modal without pressing the close button (normally you can tap away from the modal and it will close), however I can get it from not closing, but the close button still doesn't work!:

```
               $('#manageRooms').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
                 $('#manageClose').click(function (event) { //Have they pressed the close button?
                     $(this).data('clicked', 'yes');
                 }
                 );
                 if (!data) return e.preventDefault(); // stops modal from being hidden

             })
```

Comment: which plugin you are using?

Comment: bootstrap www.getbootstrap.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap modal than writing this below code can do it.

```
.modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
```

Comment: $('#manageRooms').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })

Comment: The code works but now launches the modal every time the page is loaded

Comment: can you please write your div or button html which you use to bind modal. so I can exactly guide you.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('#myModal').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
```

if html

```
<a data-controls-modal="your_div_id" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" href="#">
```

Comment: looks like the same answer of @Nimmi

Comment: Works but replica of @Nimmis answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that works but... you can try something like this:

```
$('#manageRooms').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    if(!($(event.delegateTarget).is($('#manageClose')))) return e.preventDefault();
})
```

if the modal plugin not have a different way to set the closing prop.